# Using & to get object's reference in PHP is redundant?

Tags: php, reference, object, deprecated

In PHP, all object-variables are actually pointers to objects (no?), the language handles this implicitly (right?), yet I see many php code specifying references in parameters such as this:

```
function someMethod(SomeClass& $obj)
{
//...
}
```

I've also seen things like this:

```
function add()
{
 $object = new SomeClass;
 self::$objects[] =& $object;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but there wouldn't be any difference here:

```
self::$objects[] =& new SomeClass
self::$objects[] = new SomeClass
```

Am I right??????

Another thing I tested:

```
class SomeClass{}
$obj =& new SomeClass; // is in fact deprecated, doesn't work

$obj = new SomeClass;
$obj2 =& $obj; // works, but should also be deprecated!! No?
```

Comment: Why would `=&` on another variable be deprecated?

Comment: @BoltClock: in the case that the variable is already a pointer to an object.

Comment: @user532722: what if it is not object, but `value type` variable?

Comment: @zerkms: doesn't php "know" when the variable is a pointer to an object?

Comment: @user532722: php does know, but for value type variable `= &` and `=` operators will behave differently. So there is no need to deprecate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php5, yes, it is redundant and pointless.

Comment: No it's not.  `&` creates a variable reference, which is quite different than an object reference.  See this answer for a detailed breakdown of the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611986/in-php-can-someone-explain-cloning-vs-pointer-reference/3612129#3612129

Comment: @ircmaxell: in cases OP gave us as a samples - there is no difference.

Comment: Sure there is.  The last example `$obj2 =& $obj` is very different from `$obj2 = $obj`.  Try comparing the result of executing this as the next line: `$obj2 = 'foo';`.  What's `$obj` after that?  with `=&` it's `foo` as well.  With `=` it's the original object.

Comment: @ircmaxell: i do know the difference and I do know how passing reference by value works. It is pointless to use the same variable for the different types, it is a weird practice. If you have an object and you need to store an int - create another variable. In this point of view `=&` is pointless for objects.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing related to references that is deprecated as far as I know is call-time pass-by-reference (e.g. `somefunction(&$var);`

Your code samples likely have the `&` symbol for PHP 4 compatibility. It doesn't make much of a difference whether you use `&` or not to work with object references in PHP 5. Granted there is a *slight* difference (between passing references by value in PHP 5, and using `&` to pass objects by reference), but in most cases it shouldn't affect your code when run in PHP 5.

Answer (score 0):

This page may be helpful to you:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

`new` automatically returns a reference, so you don't use the `= &` anymore with a newly declared object.

Comment: `&=` != `=&` ;-) `=&` (that is what OP asks about) is actually 2 operators `=` and `&`

Comment: you are right, my mistake, but the point is still valid. fixed.

Comment: @zerkms: I thought it was two operators too (`$somevar = a reference to $someothervar`), but according to Artefacto it is in fact a single operator. See his comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php).

Comment: @BoltClock: omg! syntactic sugar in implementation ;-) thanks for the reference

Comment: New does not return a reference.  There's nothing to reference since there's no prior object/variable.  `new` "returns" the object (in quotes since it's not really returning).  `=& new` was deprecated since it doesn't make sense (you're creating a reference to nothing).

Comment: @ircmaxell: `new` creates an object in memory and returns the reference to that object by value.

Comment: From the link above: 'As of PHP 5, the new operator returns a reference automatically, so assigning the result of new by reference results in an E_DEPRECATED message in PHP 5.3 and later, and an E_STRICT message in earlier versions.'