# Php (eval vs call_user_func vs variable functions ...)

Tags: php

Even though there's some discussions regarding this issue I wanted to check on certain example what would be the best approach.
Instead of using existing solutions I created my own persistence layer (like many do)
So my approach is also in question here.

For every table in db I have model class that has appropriate getters and setters and some mandatory methods. I also created only one generic DAO class that handles all types of model objects.
So, for example to save any model object I instantiate genericDAO class and call save method that I pass model object as attribute.
Problem is that in runtime genericDAO class doesn't know whitch model object it gets and what methods (getters and setters) exist in it, so I need to call mandatory model class method that retrieves list of attributes as multiple string array.
For example for every attribute there's array(table_column_name,attribute_name,is_string).

When I call save function it looks like this:

```
public function save(&$VO) {  
$paramArray = $VO->getParamArray();//get array of attributes
$paramIdArray = $paramArray[0];  //first attribute is always id
/*create and execute getId() and store value into $void to check if it's save or update*/
eval('$voId = $VO->get'.ucfirst($paramIdArray[1]).'();');  
...
```

Currently I'm using eval to execute those methods, but as it is well known eval is very slow.
I'm thinking of changing that into call_user_func method
Something like:

```
$voId = call_user_func(array($VO, 'get'.ucfirst($paramIdArray[1])));
```

But also there's other solutions. I can maybe use something like this

```
$method = 'get'.ucfirst($paramIdArray[1]));
$voId = $VO->$method();
```

or else

```
$method = 'get'.ucfirst($paramIdArray[1]));
$voId = $VO->{$method}();
```

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, there's no need to pass references like you are doing.  You should [give this a read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611986/in-php-can-someone-explain-cloning-vs-pointer-reference/3612129#3612129) to try to understand how PHP handles object references.

So `public function save(&$VO) {` should become `public function save($VO) {`.

Second, there is no need to use `eval` (in fact, it's better not to because of speed, debugability, etc).  You can't stack-trace an `eval` call like you can a dynamic one.

Third, `call_user_func` is all but useless since PHP supports dynamic variable functions.  Instead of `call_user_func(array($obj, $method), $arg1)`, just call `$obj->$foo($arg1)`.  The `call_user_func_array` function is still useful since it supports variable length arguments and supports passing references.

So, ultimately, I would suggest this:

```
$method = 'get' . ucfirst($paramIdArray[1]);
$voId = $VO->$method();
```

Note that there's no need to call `method_exists`, since it may be callable and not exist due to `__get` magic method support...

Comment: I think `call_user_func()` is still the only way to call an anonymous function stored in object variable: `$o->f = function() {};` trying to do `$o->f()` will result in `$o doesn't hav a method named 'f'` warning.

Comment: @Mchl: `$c = $o->f; $c();` will work.  Or you can implement a `__call` magic method to do it for you.  But you don't *have* to use `call_user_func`.  And that's the point of what I was trying to say.  It doesn't do anything that you can't do in native language...  It may be easier to do and read, but it's not doing anything special...

Comment: Ah yes. Forgot about `$c = $o->f; $c();`, You're right about that.

Comment: @ircmaxell
Thanks for advice but the reason I decided to do pass-by-reference is because after save I can retrieve ID from database and set ID in the object. That way I can reuse that object in the remaining code.

Comment: @aleksandar: Objects are passed by reference by default... as long as it is an object there is no reason to use the `&` operator...

Comment: @ircmaxell: I was confused a bit after reading a docs. Now you clarify that. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm developing an MVC similar to SilverStripe, and this: "Note that there's no need to call method_exists, since it may be callable and not exist due to __get magic method support..." helped me see that I could simplify my dispatcher method and at the same time add Controller class flexibility. Thanks!

Comment: Another alternative to above... `$c = array($o,'f'); $c();`

Comment: "Objects are passed by reference by default" - this is not strictly true. The reason we don't need to use the `&` operator is because objects are stored differently in PHP 5. An object _identifier_ is still copied (but not the object itself as what would have happened in PHP 4).

Comment: I hadn't; I have now. :) I was just responding to @prodigitalson's comment above (although it was a while ago). Yes, I agree with your linked post, specifically, "variables which store an object as storing the pointer to that object" - the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) refers to this "pointer" as an "object identifer". However, personally, I would not use the term "object reference" as you have done, specifically the word "reference". Since it's not a user-land "reference" and using that word is just confusing IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I normally would use:

```
$method = 'get'.ucfirst($attribute);
if(method_exists($obj, $method){
  $obj->$method();
}
```

But unless there is a very good reason i would just return a `key => value` array from `getParamArray`. And operate on that instead of using the getters...

Comment: Yes, it's probably faster if avoid using getters... until they create private access modifier :)