# PHP - How to rename an object property?

Tags: php, oop, properties

I wonder how can I rename an object property in PHP, e.g.:

```
<?php
    $obj = new stdclass();
    $obj->a = 10;  // will be renamed
    $obj->b = $obj->a; // rename "a" to "b", somehow!
    unset($obj->a); // remove the original one
```

It does not work in PHP5.3, (donno about earlier versions) since there will be a reference of `$obj->a` assigned to `$obj->b` and so by unsetting `$obj->a`, the value of `$obj->b` will be null. Any ideas please?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.4 
after executing your code $obj: 
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["b"]=> int(10) }

Comment: It's not a reference.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611986/in-php-can-someone-explain-cloning-vs-pointer-reference/3612129#3612129) for details on PHP handles writing variables and references...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code works correctly, `$obj->b` is `10` after execution: http://codepad.org/QnXvueic

When you unset `$obj->a`, you just remove the property, you do not touch to the value. If the value is used by an other variable, it's left untouched in the order variable.

Comment: That's handy. It saves having to do reflection and other fancy stuff like in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php     
$obj = new stdclass();
$obj->a = 10;  // will be renamed
$obj->b = $obj->a; // rename "a" to "b", somehow!
unset($obj->a); // remove the original one
var_dump($obj->b); //10 Works fine
```

Comment: That's not a rename, it's a copy.
It will occupy twice the memory of ->a.

Just saying as "renaming" is often only something important to developers who handle large datasets.

Answer (score -1):

Use object clonning, Reference : [PHP __clone() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)