# If Objects are passed by alias when would you pass by reference?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [In PHP can someone explain cloning vs pointer reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611986/in-php-can-someone-explain-cloning-vs-pointer-reference)

According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

> One of the key-points of PHP 5 OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true. This section rectifies that general thought using some examples.
>
> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

If objects are passed by alias or handler then in what situation would you actually want to pass by reference?

```
myFunc($obj); // Pass by alias/handler

myFunc(& $obj); // Pass by reference (when would you do this?)

myFunc(clone $obj); // Create a new object
```

What are the different use-cases for each of these?

Comment: I think this lecture covered the topic: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxxIXPc9IR8 (among other things)

Comment: Note, call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated since at least 5.3, if not earlier.  The function declares which args it expects to be references, and the caller doesn't have to specify that they're references -- and, in fact, shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the different use-cases for each of these?

You already named the three different use-cases:

1. Passing an object as parameter
2. Passing an alias as parameter
3. Passing an object clone as parameter

Naturally you do each of these three things when you need to do the specific case. You normally only need 1. in 99.9%. You do the other 0.1% when you need to.

An examlary use-case (as asked for in comments) for a variable alias as parameter as a little example ([Demo](http://codepad.org/1Ww0N8iY)):

```
class VarFreezer
{
    private $alias;
    private $value;
    public function __construct(&$object) {
        $this->alias = &$object;
        $this->value = $object;
    }
    public function restore()
    {
        $this->alias = $this->value;
    }
}

$var = new stdClass();
$var->value = 'I am an object now.';

$freezer = new VarFreezer($var);

$var = 'I am a string now.';

$freezer->restore();

var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Any idea what a specific use-case would be for `myFunc(& $obj)`?

Comment: That is specifically passing a variable alias as parameter. So you can reference the same variable with a second name.

Comment: @Dev I'm asking specifically about objects and their behavior when passed into functions - not primitives like strings.

Comment: If you pass a reference it's more about the variable name than the actual value.

Comment: @MikeB: I added some example code that shows for what these aliases could be used.

Answer (score 2):

When you give an object to a method the reference to the existing objects is passed so that you have the variable in the calling scope and the method parameter variable in the method's scope both referencing to the same object.

You can explicitly use & to give an reference to a primitive like an array, so that an invoked method can change the data of the original array. For objects this is the default nowadays as you mentioned.

A clone seems obvious.

With &$obj you create an alias to $obj not a reference to the object $obj refers to. Quoting php.net:

```
$c = new A;
$d = &$c;
$c->foo = 2;
$c = NULL;
echo $d->foo."\n"; // Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object...
```

Answer (score 2):

myfunc($obj) //pass in identifier

For when your function needs to get access to the object and manipulate/ read from it somehow.

myfunc(& $obj) //pass in reference to the identifier.

The key here is that your passing a reference to the identifier. Which means that if the outer variable ($obj) is set to null, then the inner object also becomes null because you've removed the identifier from $obj and so the reference to it has also been removed. Unlike when you pass in the identifier because what your actually doing it passing in a copy of the identifier and so if $obj was set to null then the value inside the function would still point to the object.

example:

```
var x = new Object();

var y = x //y and x both contain **different** identifiers to the same object in memory.

function a($_a){} // a function for examples

a($y) // passes in a copy of $y so $_a (inside the function) is a third identifier pointing to th in memory object

a(& $y) // now $_a contains the **same** identifier as $y so if either is emptied then the other is also emptied. 

a(clone $y) //creates a new object identical to the first and passes in an identifier of the new object.
```

hope thats clear enough.

you would pass an identifier by reference if you want to be able to modify or delete the identifier from inside the function and have it affect the external identifier variable whilst being able to return an independently calculated value. e.g serialize an object, save it to a file return the file string but also clear the identifier so the object can be cleared from memory.